# How can I create a checked listbox of Wordpress categories?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

The first thing I tried was the following

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" />
    <label for="check1">
         <ul id="selectable0">
              <li><?php wp_list_cats(); ?></li> 
        </ul>
</label>
```

This just creates a single checkbox. What I want to have is a listbox with a checkbox beside each item.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories();
foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="<?php echo $category->cat_ID; ?>"><?php echo $category->cat_name;?><br>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: with this code i cant select checkbox... In fact, there is no checkbox. <<only text>>

Comment: i'm found problem, jQuery added 'ui-helper-hidden-accessible' class to checkbox element. i'm solved this problem but i have new problem....__ .buttonset() jQuery function doesn't work....__ http://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox